# Excel Pivottable Subtract Two Columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out how to find net growth in a workforce in a pivotable. As of right now, I have a column that says status and consist of "Hire" and "Separation". I have these both in the pivotable as count of. For example, it could say 6 hire and 2 separation. However, when I do subtotal to see the net growth, it shows these two values added not subtracted. I need it to do subtotal of "hire" count - "separation" count.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know that inserting a calculated field will not work as you cannot calculate a field based of the value of another column

Comment: I'm a bit confused when you say that you "*have these both in the pivotable as count of*". Aren't "Hire" and "Separation" two entries from the same column within your data? In which case you'd have that column, e.g. 'Status' as the Rows or Columns field in your Pivot Table with 'Count of Status' in the Values field.

Comment: @JosWoolley yes you are correct with 'Status' as the columns and then 'Count of Status' as the values. I am then trying find the overall net growth by subtracting the separations from hires which are the options for status

Comment: It will need to be done via `Power Pivot`, using a `Measure`. If you want this metric to be included in your current Pivot Table, it will be as an additional column, so for aesthetic reasons you'll need to decide whether you want it to be displayed in the same row as 'Hire', 'Separation' or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this a little differently, by not using subtotals.  Instead, drag Status to your value field twice.  The first will show you the number of hires and fires.  Then, click the second Count > Value Field Settings > Show Values As.  Choose Difference From in the dropdown.  Base field is status and Base item is previous.

[image]

This will add a second column showing the Net Growth (or loss) of each grouping.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Jody! I got this to work. If I want to add another layer , its say Department name, is that possible to do easily?

Comment: @ttucker34 Yes, just put the department in the Rows field in between the Date and Status